# Writing a state respective to the eigenbasis of an observable

Tags: quantum-state, measurement

**Problem:**

When people say that a state $|\mathcal{A}\rangle$ can be expressed in respect to the eigenbasis of an observable $A$, they provide $p_{\mathcal{A}}(a)$, which apparently gives the distribution of the state $\mathcal{A}$ with respect to the eigenbasis of $A$.

**Question:**

What does $a$ mean in your opinion? (and yes, the above is all they say, no clarification whatsoever)

**My thoughts:**

$a$ is an eigenvalue, meaning one can write $|\mathcal{A}\rangle=\sum_a p_{\mathcal{A}}(a) |a\rangle$ if $A=\sum_a a|a\rangle\langle a|$. On the other side, this doesn't work if eigenvalues are degenerate...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your thoughts are likely accurate. In the case of degeneracy, you probably want
$$
A=\sum_aaP_a
$$
where $a$ are the unique eigenvalues and $P_a$ are the projectors onto that subspace (the projectors may have rank larger than 1). Then,
$$
p_{\mathcal{A}}(a)=\langle\mathcal{A}|P_a|\mathcal{A}\rangle.
$$
What you lose in the case of degeneracy is the ability to infer the state $|\mathcal{A}\rangle$ just from the values $p_{\mathcal{A}}$, but probably all you're trying to do is get the expectation value $\sum_aap_{\mathcal{A}}(a)$ which you can get.